# New tokens to existing language

Tags: monaco-editor

I am using Monaco editor in our project and I have issue I am not able to overcome.
At our scenario , user can add new words to the editor once he clicks on a button, for example, user has editor with language javascript and he now wants to add new word 'workTest', it should be highlighted in custom color.
How do I add new tokens to the editor with highlighted colors?
I already have my 'newTheme' with rules {token: 'asToken', foreground: 'FFA500', fontStyle: 'bold'}
How do I add the tokens to an existing language? I tried everything and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

The tokenization is done using a dynamic tokenizer (see the [Monarch declarative syntax highlighter](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html) documentation). All keywords are specified in JS code, via a Regex rule.

You could create your own tokenizer and update that with each new keyword.